# How to Bind the Wikitude aar file in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

Hi I am trying to bind wikitude .aar fine in xamarin...I am having some issues

```
Com.Wikitude.Tracker.IObjectTrackerListener.cs(47,47): Error CS0102: The type 'TargetsLoadedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' (CS0102) (AarBinding)

Com.Wikitude.Tracker.IObjectTrackerListener.cs(14,14): Error CS0102: The type 'ErrorLoadingTargetsEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P1' (CS0102) (AarBinding)
```

I tried to use the Metadata.xml as

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='Com.Wikitude.Tracker']/class[@name='ErrorLoadingTargetsEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">p0_2</attr>
```

But it is now working any suggestions Please ?

Comment: The Java package name is wrong, should be the all lower case Java package name, not the C# normalized version

Comment: hi @SushiHangover I tried that but still not working   <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wikitude.tracker']/class[@name='ErrorLoadingTargetsEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">p01</attr>

Comment: Look at the generated C# wrappers (`obj/Debug/generated/src`), each class/method/property contains its XPATH, you can copy/paste those into your transforms

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/8409815aead562f140270fcbe19e87fb.html  and error code is specified above

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover I already tried it...I am worried now  it seems strange....I have added generated file link in above comment

Comment: Please use a more reputable source to upload your error message such as github's gist. Otherwise just edit your question with the relevant error message. As an additional item, please also include a link to where one can find the Wikitude aar file. You should be able to follow an example here: https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/9607158#file-metadata-xml-L8-L11 In other words you need to completely change this metadata definition as it's an interface and you need to change the argsType.

Comment: Hi @JonDouglas , SushiHangover Thanks for the advice it worked :)....

Comment: Please post the Answer for others who might run into this!

Comment: typo: `Metdata.xml` instead of `Metadata.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was as able to fix this issue..It may be helpful for others

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
          <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wikitude.tracker']/interface[@name='ObjectTrackerListener']/method[@name='onTargetsLoaded']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">tracker</attr> 
           <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wikitude.tracker']/interface[@name='ObjectTrackerListener']/method[@name='onErrorLoadingTargets']/parameter[1]" name="managedName">tracker</attr>
           <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wikitude.tracker']/interface[@name='ObjectTrackerListener']/method[@name='onErrorLoadingTargets']/parameter[2]" name="managedName">errorCode</attr> 
           <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.wikitude.tracker']/interface[@name='ObjectTrackerListener']/method[@name='onErrorLoadingTargets']/parameter[3]" name="managedName">errorMessage</attr>  
       <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.pbar.samples']/class[@name='StartActivity']" 
         name="visibility">public</attr>
</metadata>
```